# Quit method explanation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If I open FB manually , and I open Gmail by using automation and if we use quit() method, whether it will close both manual one and automation one  or only which I opened in automation it will close.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it to get an (useful) answer. As it is now it's almost impossible to understand what is the context, what are your expectations and what goes wrong.

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens? It would have been faster then opening an account and posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

It will close the one which opened in automation

Answer (score 0):

Good Question.

driver.quit() this method will close all the web driver session initialized browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you open FB manually and Gmail by using automation with the Quit() method, It will always close your browser which is initialized by the selenium web driver. Selenium web driver will never allow you to quit or close browsers that open manually.

In the below-attached screenshot of the code, you can see the browser path for Chrome provided which is initialized and run in a separate browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWBVc.png)